# Extraer dato de tabla relacionada mysql a través de php

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un problema a la hora de extraer un dato en mysql a través de PHP.
Tengo una base de datos con dos tablas relacionadas entre sí, la tabla *usuarios* está relacionada su "Id" con otra tabla llamada *contenido* en el apartado "creador". Lo que busco es extraer de la tabla *usuarios* otro dato llamado "usuario", que sería el nombre en relación a el id, pero solo logro sacar el id, es decir el número de identificación y no el nombre.

Aquí les dejo mi código.

```
<?php 
    include("apartadosPhp/conexion_bd.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contenido ORDER BY fecha DESC";
                  $resultado = $conexion -> query($query);
                  while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            ?>
            <div>
                <div class="img">   
                    <img class="imgEntrada" src="img/entradas/<?php echo $row ['Img']?>" alt="imgEntrada">
                </div>
                <div class="detalles">
                    <h3><?php echo $row['Titulo'] ?></h3>
                    <h4 class="creador"> <?php echo $row['creador'] ?> </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            
        }
?>
```

En el momento de poner `$row['creador']` me imprime el ID del usuario que registró la entrada, pero busco extraer el nombre, no el id.

Comment: añade la estructura de tus tablas. Probablemente la solución sea  hacer un `join` en tu consulta.

Comment: @Sr1871 acabo de subir una foto de la base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *En el momento de poner $row['creador'] me imprime el ID del usuario que registró la entrada, pero busco extraer el nombre, no el id.*

Así debe ser, `creador` es la columna numérica que sirve para relacionar las filas de tu tabla `contenido` con tu tabla `usuarios`. El hecho de que exista una relación entre tablas no significa que cuando consultes a esa tabla sola te traerá datos de las tablas relacionadas, sino que en la instrucción SQL debes indicar las relaciones mediante `JOIN`, entonces podrás obtener los datos de todas las tablas que hayas puesto en la instrucción SQL.

Por ejemplo, puedes definir así tu variable `$query`:

```
SELECT 
    c.Img, 
    c.Titulo, 
    u.nombre 
FROM contenido AS c 
INNER JOIN usuarios AS u ON c.contenido = u.id
ORDER BY c.fecha DESC
```

El `INNER JOIN` te traerá datos tanto de `usuarios` como de `contenido`. En vez de `$row['creador']` usa ahora `$row['nombre']`, que será el nombre del usuario.

Supongamos que te interesa también el cargo, pues puedes seguir relacionando:

```
SELECT 
    c.Img, 
    c.Titulo, 
    u.nombre,
    ca.descripcion 
FROM contenido AS c 
INNER JOIN usuarios AS u ON c.contenido = u.id
INNER JOIN cargo AS ca ON u.perfil = ca.id
ORDER BY c.fecha DESC
```

Ahí tendrás a mano también la columna `descripcion` de la tabla `cargo`. Por cierto, la columna `perfil int(50)` en `usuarios` no es del mismo tamaño que la columna `id int(11)`  en `cargo`, en un entorno de definición correcto de llaves primarias / foráneas para gestionar de forma automática la integridad referencial te dará error.

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez una consulta como esta te puede devolver los datos que necesitas:

```
select c.id, c.categoria, c.titulo, u.usuario
from contenido c
inner join usuarios u on u.id = c.creador
order by c.titulo;
```

Como norma general, no conviene usar el `*` y además no sirve cuando vas a usar varias tablas relacionadas y extraer datos de ellas.